# SSRS How to match rectangle peer heights to avoid spacing issues in Word exports?

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word

## **Quick Summary**

I have an issue that only occurs when exporting my SSRS report to a Word document (something clients have requested). In short, when rectangle is shorter than its peer, Word inserts a page break even if there is plenty of whitespace left to render the longer column all on one page. I would like to resolve this so that Word takes advantage of the entire page when the peers are of different heights.

## **Layout**

The highest level of the layout consists of three rectangles, as shown below:

[image]

- The left and right rectangles are of **fixed widths**, but **variable heights**.
- There is no extra space at the bottom of the Parent Rectangle; it expands based on the contents of the other two.
- Each rectangle several other items and uses **multiple datasets**.
- There are rectangles inside the rectangles, which group some of the child objects together.
- Some of the controls are textboxes. I don't know the length of the text at design time.

## **Word Export Result**

[image]

- There is enough empty space above the footer to hold the entire left column, with excess.
- If I open the document and manually enter empty lines into the right-hand column to increase its height, items from the left-hand column which have a height equal to or less than those line breaks will float back up to the first page. This is what makes me believe Word is cutting off at the shortest of the two peers.

**Things I've Tried**

- Another thread suggested putting the columns into a table instead of rectangles, to force them to expand together. However, it required that they use the same dataset, which they do not.
- Looked for CanGrow or ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace type options that could apply to rectangles, but couldn't find any. ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace is set to true on the report itself but makes no difference.
- Attempted to create a function to dynamically set the inner rectangles' height, or the height/padding of a hidden textbox, based on the longer peer. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything for fetching the height at runtime; the functions I found all rely on knowing static data such as the number of rows (of a fixed height) in the sheet, but each column has several fields of which the height is unknown prior to loading data.
- Extended the height of each rectangle to that of a full page by default and tried to find a way to make the elements inside consume this empty space as needed. The space was never consumed, and always pushed down, resulting in an extra page of whitespace.

### **Question**

Is there any way to notify Word to use its available whitespace rather than cutting off at the shortest peer? I've been looking for a long while and keep coming up empty-handed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of using a rectangle, you use a **List** with two columns?

I think the list will do better with pagination than the rectangle. YMMV - Not sure how it exports to WORD.

Put your left rectangle in the first column and the right rectangle in the second column.

Use the same data set and Group on **1** (the number) so there's just one row.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this just now to see whether it would work, but the list has the same problem as the table solution: it throws off my DataSets and gives errors for the components inside the rectangles. Several different DataSets are used in each column, so I think all Tablix layout replacements are probably out as they'd all have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I managed to make it work by adding a horizontal line that take the whole width of the main rectangle just below the two child rectangles